# ignoreTitle not working in IE

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using jquery validation and I have one mobilePhone input field and it is not mandatory field but if the user enters any number I am masking it using:

```
$('#mobilePhone').mask('000-000-0000');
```

and I put the validation message when the user enters any wrong data in mobile phone field "Format of the Phone Number should be xxx-xxx-xxxx". But while clicking on submit button without entering any data into mobile phone field it is throwing the validation message "Format of the Phone Number should be xxx-xxx-xxxx". which is wrong.

Below is the code for mobilePhone validation message:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneUS", function(phone_number,
                    element) {
                phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, "");
                return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9
                        && phone_number.match(/^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/);
            }, "Format of the Phone Number should be xxx-xxx-xxxx");


"mobilePhone" : {
                        phoneUS : true
                    }
```

This issue happening in IE only but it is working fine in firefox and chrome.Could you please tell me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After digging I fixed this issue, I removed the

```
"mobilePhone" : { phoneUS : true }
```

and added the `data-rule` directly in the field.